# How do I line up input fields and their labels in a grid like manner with css?

Tags: css

I'm trying to do something that must be relatively easy, but I've spent hours mucking around with this and I'm no getting to the answer.

I need to layout some input fields and their layers on a grid (or like a table I guess) with

```
lable     input      label input
label     input      label input
```

Because the input fields are different widths (and would look pretty crappy if they were all the same width) the best I've managed to get is

```
label     input    label  input
label     logerinput    label  input
```

How do I line up the second set of labels and there inputs?

I've made two classes for the labels

```
#dpi_form label { 
  display: inline-block; 
  width: 150px; 
  margin-left: 20px;
}
#dpi_form .right-label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  margin-left: 220px; 
}
```

and the associated controls are

```
  <label for="req_retailer_index_fld">Select the retailer*:</label><select id="req_retailer_index_fld" name="req_retailer_index_fld" class="required selectbox ui-widget-content"><option>item 1</option><option>item 2</option></select>
  <label for="req_region_index_fld" class="right-label">Select the region*:</label><select id="req_region_index_fld" name="req_region_index_fld" class="required selectbox ui-widget-content"><option>item 1</option><option>item 2</option></select><br />
  <label for="req_customer_type_index_fld">Select the customer type*:</label><select id="req_customer_type_index_fld" name="req_customer_type_index_fld" class="required selectbox ui-widget-content"><option>item 1</option><option>item 2</option></select>
  <label for="req_meter_state_index_fldi" class="right-label">Select the meter state*:</label><select id="req_meter_state_index_fld" name="req_meter_state_index_fld" class="required selectbox ui-widget-content"><option>item 1</option><option>item 2</option></select><br />
```

within a div.

I've tried absolute positioning, relative positioning, padding, all manner of right and left margins but still can't get the result I'm after.

I can find heaps of stuff or vertical alignment of controls.. but nothing showing me how to do this one.

Any clues please?

Peter.

Comment: Your example code lines up in a grid style for me in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/45AaD/ - I see this: http://i.imgur.com/hIR2T.jpg - isn't that what you're after?

Comment: You should use a table really. What you want could be done if you added extra markup with divs and more CSS, but by the time you have achieved your desired result it would have been quicker and easier to just use a table. Why re-invent the wheel?

Comment: @Sour Lemon, because your mark-up will be better. Specifically, it will be more accessible for non-graphical browsers (like google crawler, to name a big one -- easy way to boost your traffic, make it easy for google to read your site), and simpler, generally easier to read code (for humans).

Comment: @mwan -- his code lines up because he chose an example that doesn't really exemplify his problem. In his example, all his inputs are the same size. Make one of them in the left larger too see the problem.

Comment: @mwan, for example: http://jsfiddle.net/45AaD/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Despite my comment about using tables on your question, this is how I would do it.

CSS:

```
label,
input {
    display: block;
}
label {
    padding: 4px 0 0;
}
.labels1 {
    float: left;
    width: 80px;
}
.labels2 {
    float: left;
    width: 80px;
}
.inputs1 {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
}
.inputs2 {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="labels1">
    <label for="input1">Input 1: </label>
    <label for="input2">Input 2: </label>
    <label for="input3">Input 2: </label>
</div>

<div class="inputs1">
    <input type="text" value="" name="input1" id="input1" />
    <input type="text" value="" name="input2" id="input2" />
    <input type="text" value="" name="input3" id="input3" />
</div>

<div class="labels2">
    <label for="input4">Input 4: </label>
    <label for="input5">Input 5: </label>
    <label for="input6">Input 6: </label>
</div>

<div class="inputs2">
    <input type="text" value="" name="input4" id="input4" />
    <input type="text" value="" name="input5" id="input5" />
    <input type="text" value="" name="input6" id="input6" />
</div>
```

Then you can change the labels and inputs classes to the width you want.
Although I still think tables are easier because then you don't have to worry about setting widths yourself; you also don't have to worry about vertical alignment with tables.

Comment: If you want to layout it like a table, you can still name your classes semantically, but layout it out like a table using `display: table;`, `display: table-cell;` and `display: table-row;`. Then it will render just like a table, but the mark-up will be so much better -- more accessible for non-graphical browsers (like google crawler, to name a big one -- easy way to boost your traffic, make it easy for google to read your site), and simpler, generally easier to read code (for humans).

Answer (score 2):

use following styles.

for parent container

```
display: table;
```

for row container

```
display: table-row;
```

for cell container

```
display: table-cell;
```

**example**

```
<div style="display: table;">
  <div style="display: table-row;">
    <div style="display: table-cell;">
      lable
    </div>  
    <div style="display: table-cell;">
      input
    </div>  
    <div style="display: table-cell;">
      label input
    </div>  
  </div>
  <div>
    <div style="display: table-cell;">
      lable
    </div>  
    <div style="display: table-cell;">
      input
    </div>  
    <div style="display: table-cell;">
      label input
    </div>  
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Or... You know.  Use a table.

Comment: Or name your elements semantically with classes, then use css to apply the appropriate table-like styles, rather than inlining them. If you are going to inline like this, it's not much better than an actual table.

Comment: i just put inline styles just to easily understand.

Answer (score 1):

Use a table, that's what they are for.

Comment: But ZOMGOSH tables are evil... :P +1

Comment: Taken from http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#h-11.1 : **Tables should not be used purely as a means to layout document content**. The information he's presenting isn't tabular, so it's not what tables are for.

Comment: Personally I would rather use a table than fiddle with CSS for weeks to get it looking right in all browsers. I think it allows more consistency. I'm by no means amazing with CSS though!

Comment: If you want to layout it like a table, you can still code semantically, but layout it out like a table using `display: table;`, `display: table-cell;`, and `display: table-row;`. Then it will render just like a table, but the mark-up will be so much better -- more accessible for non-graphical browsers (like google crawler, to name a big one -- easy way to boost your traffic, make it easy for google to read your site), and simpler, generally easier to read code (for humans)

Comment: In this case, a table would NOT be used for laying out a document so the caveat from W3 does not apply.

Comment: @ben lee.. can you expand on this a bit please? Example code perhaps?

Comment: @PeterNUnn, see @Chamika Sandamal's answer for an example of using `display: table...` styles.

Comment: @SteveWellens It is absolutely using tables to layout non-tabular data. There is no information encoded in 2-dimensions. You're not looking things up by row and column. The fact one input is in the same column as another has no meaning. There is nothing intrinsically tabular about the form; you could just as easily put labels above the inputs, or inside them. That decision is a presentation concern. The only reason to make inputs line up is to make it look aesthetically pleasing (which isn't a bad thing). It's a tabular layout, sure, but it's not tabular data.

Comment: @IRC - I disagree.  The information may not be data appropriate for a table like a spreadsheet, but the thing that matters is he wants the data in a grid layout.  A grid is a grid, it doesn't matter if the data isn't tabular.  BTW:  I'm not sure what the policy here is on necro-posting but this is a pretty old question.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a table or **for a pure CSS solution** maybe the 960 grid system [960.gs](http://960.gs/)

Answer (score 1):

I would use [floats](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/css-floats-101/). Here's a jsfiddle showing how I would do it:

http://jsfiddle.net/pSsap/

I'll reproduce the code below.

With html like this:

```
<form class="grid">
    <section>
        <label for="wind">wind</label>
        <span class="field"><input id="wind" name="wind" type="input" class="regular"></span>
        <label for="earth">earth</label>
        <span class="field"><input id="earth" name="earth" type="input" class="regular"></span>
    </section>
    <section>
        <label for="fire">fire</label>
        <span class="field"><input id="fire" name="fire" type="input" class="long"></span>
        <label for="air">air</label>
        <span class="field"><input id="air" name="air" type="input" class="regular"></span>
    </section>
</form>
```

And css like this:

```
form.grid section {
    clear: both;
}

form.grid section label, form.grid section span.field {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

form.grid section label {
    width: 50px;
}

form.grid section span.field {
    width: 150px;
}

input.regular {
    width: 100px;
}

input.long {
    width: 140px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solutions:

1. Use a list: `<ol>` or `<ul>`
2. Set a width for that list: *(in the example, `960px` is the width of the `<ul>`)*
3. Float the lists: `<li>` and set a width to limit its floating point: *(in the example, `320px` is the set width)*
4. If you want to have a consistent alignment with the `<label>` and `<select>` pairs, set a width to the `<label>` *(make sure you set it as a block-level element first: in the example, the `<label>` was set to `160px`)*
5. Make sure to clear *(`clear: left`)* any elements following this list *(`<ul>`)* used.

### The Markup:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <label for="req_retailer_index_fld">Select the retailer*:</label>
        <select id="req_retailer_index_fld" name="req_retailer_index_fld" class="required selectbox ui-widget-content">
            <option>item 1</option><option>item 2</option>
        </select>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="req_region_index_fld" class="right-label">Select the region*:</label>
        <select id="req_region_index_fld" name="req_region_index_fld" class="required selectbox ui-widget-content">
            <option>item 1</option><option>item 2</option>
        </select>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="req_customer_type_index_fld">Select the customer type*:</label>
        <select id="req_customer_type_index_fld" name="req_customer_type_index_fld" class="required selectbox ui-widget-content">
            <option>item 1</option><option>item 2</option>
        </select>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="req_meter_state_index_fldi" class="right-label">Select the meter state*:</label>
        <select id="req_meter_state_index_fld" name="req_meter_state_index_fld" class="required selectbox ui-widget-content">
            <option>item 1</option><option>item 2</option>
        </select>
    </li>
</ul>
```

### The CSS

```
ul {
    background: #EEE;
    width: 960px;
}
li {
    background: #FFC0CB;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    width: 320px;
}
label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 160px;
}
```

The result is that, the list will just drop when the `<ul>` can't contain it any longer *(since you have set a width in it)*. On the other hand, the width of the `<li>`s will consistently make them align to each other, while being floated.